# Ability to overwrite react-native-navigation's default tab navigation stack behavior

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

#### Issue Description

With regards to navigation on `BottomTabs` generated from `Navigation.startTabBasedApp`: It's my understanding that each tab keeps track of it's own navigation stack - meaning that if I navigate as follows:

`tab1 -> screen1 -> screen2 -> tab3 -> tab1`

that I will still be on `screen2`. Is there a way to overwrite this behavior so that when I press on a tab's icon, it navigates to that tab's initial screen regardless of how many screens it has on its stack?

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 1.1.457
- React Native version: 0.55.3
- Platform(s): both
- Device info: Nexus 5 Emulator with Android 8.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using one stack navigator for each of your tabs.

Comment: How would I go about this?